# Correct syntax for str_replace replacing spaces with underscore

Tags: magento, preg-replace, str-replace

Unsure of the correct syntax to add `str_replace(' ', '_')` to the below:-

```
<?php echo strtolower ($manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')) ?>
```

Have tried all sorts of variations such as this:-

```
<?php echo strtolower (str_replace(' ', '_'), $manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer')) ?>
```

But nothing I've tried seems to be working because I'm not getting the syntax correct...

Perhaps `preg_replace` would even be better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to move your `)` more to the right.
The `str_replace` method takes 3 parameters (actually 4 but the forth is not important now).

You call it like `str_replace(' ', '_')`.
I think you need this:

```
$manufacturerName = $_product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
echo strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $manufacturerName));
```

Comment: Ah I see, excellent, that works a treat, thanks @Marius (will accept in 9 mins).

Answer (score 0):

```
here is an example of STR_REPLACE function :

// Replacements order
$str     = "Line 1\nLine 2\rLine 3\r\nLine 4\n";
$order   = array("\r\n", "\n", "\r");
$replace = '<br />';
$newstr = str_replace($order, $replace, $str);

I hope it'll helps
```

Comment: Yes I could understand the examples I could find on `str_replace` such as this, I just wasn't sure how to modify my existing code to include `str_replace`. Thanks.